# How to optimize XQuery fn:count() in FLWOR (Parallelize)?

Tags: xml, database, xquery, basex, xml-database

I'm using BaseX XML database and have a lot of XML data, approximately 50 000 files of various size.
However, one of my local functions I have implemented are to computational heavy. Unfortunately it is very crucial in my work.

Let us assume I have 50 000 files for every Student, and every Student has an attribute called `friend`. I want to find out for *each* Student, how many friends the Student has.

Here are some example code:

```xml
declare variable $context := /Students

declare function local:CalculateFriends($student)
{
 let $studentName := $student/@Name
 return fn:count($context[@friend = $studentName])
}

for $s in $context
let $numberOfFriends := local:CalculateFriends($s)
return <Student Name = '{$s/@Name}' NumberOfFriends = '{$numberOfFriends}' />
```

This code works fine for one *single* student. For 1000 students, it takes approximately 5 minutes. Imagine for 50 000 students. It either crashes or gets timeout, I cannot debug it. Left it to calculate overnight and came back, nothing happened.

Is there a way to optimize this? Since using `@friend = $studentName` it makes use of attribute index (it is enabled). Having taken a parallel course in university, my first thought was to parallelize the count and flwor statement into chunks, similar to OpenMP. But after some research it does not seem to support parallelized queries.

Anyone have any idea on how to approach this problem?

Thanks!

EDIT: Example of XML structure

```xml
<Student Name="Kevin" friend="Alvin" BirthDate="1985-06-29" etc..>
  <More meta data> ....... />
</Student>
```

Comment: Your code example contains multiple syntax errors (missing semicolons) and the document structure is not clear from the code. Is `/Students` the root node or somehow a sequence of all students? Can every student only have one outgoing friendship (since they seem to be attributes of the students)? It would be very helpful to have at least an extract of the XML file.

Comment: @LeoWörteler Hi and sorry for the late reply. `/Students` is a sequence of all students and also the root context of the database. You are also correct, every student have only one outgoing friendship which are specified in the attribute. Added a brief example of XML file in my edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems one can consider that problem as a grouping problem where the members of a group have to be counted so you could try whether

```
let 
  $friendsMap as map(xs:string, xs:integer) := 
    map:merge(
        for $student in $context
        group by $friend := $student/@Friend/string()
        return map { $friend : count($student) }
    )
for $s in $context return <Student Name = '{$s/@Name}' NumberOfFriends = '{$friendsMap($s/@Name)}' />
```

performs better, given that grouping is usually supported by the use of keys to make it more efficient.

No idea whether it helps with BaseX and that particular problem but posting as an answer instead of a comment to have some readable way to suggest the code.

The only other issue in your posted code snippets seems to be that the sample has an attribute spelled `Friend` while the XPath searches for `@friend`, not sure whether that is a typo in the question or perhaps the reason why the index doesn't work.

Comment: Absolutely amazing, I wonder how I did not think of using a map in my algorithms.  I assume using map in XQuery has the performance of O(1) lookup time which is why it is so efficient.  

Perhaps using this approach could improve my performance in other algorithms. Thank you! Marked as answer.